# Updating JDO Embeded Entity Field

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I'm working with JDO embedded entities. I've gotten the parent and child entities set up just fine by [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses#Embedded_Classes). My problem is that I can't seem to get changes I make to the child entity to persist. Here are my two classes:

Parent:

```java
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class TestEntity {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Persistent
    private String name;

    @Persistent
    @Embedded
    private TestEntitySub sub;

    public TestEntitySub getSub() {
        return sub;
    }

    public void setSub(TestEntitySub sub) {
        this.sub = sub;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Child:

```java
@PersistenceCapable
@EmbeddedOnly
public class TestEntitySub {
    @Persistent
    private String state;

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

Code to modify:

```java
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
TestEntity test = pm.getObjectById(TestEntity.class, 75L); //object has id=75
test.getSub().setState("New State");    
pm.makePersistent(test);
pm.close();
```

The code runs without error, but the datastore shows no changes. I've tried various combinations of also persisting the child object, resetting the child's field in the parent, etc., to no effect. If I modify the parent's `name` instead of the child's `state` it works just fine. So how to I modify the child's fields?

Answer (score 1):

I'd still love a more legitimate answer, but for anyone else struggling with this, I did find a workaround:

```java
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
TestEntity test = pm.getObjectById(TestEntity.class, 75L); //object has id=75
TestEntitySub sub = test.getSub();  //Get the embedded entity
sub = pm.detachCopy(sub);           //Make a detached copy
sub.setState("New State");          //Update it
test.setSub(sub);                   //set it as the new embedded entity
pm.makePersistent(test);            //and persist the parent
pm.close();
```

The downside is that the PM has to make a complete copy of your embedded object. I'm assuming there's a better way, so if you know one, please share.